# Fragment Transaction .replace() method throwing null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have a program whose default UI is a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`.  The `MainActivity` is a `CoordinatorLayout`.  The `Viewpager`, `AppBarLayout`, and `TabLayout` are all wrapped in a `RelativeLayout` that I intend to use as a container for swapping the main UI out for a different view.

Hosted in one of the `ViewPager` views is a button.  This button communicates with `MainActivity` via an interface called `HelperLinkerListener`, which the `MainActivity` implements.  I know that the interface is wired up correctly because I've tested it via logcat.

I'd *like* to have the button swap out my wrapper `RelativeLayout` for a new fragment.  Here is the current content of my `onHelperLinkerClick()`:

```
    Fragment fragment = new GsonPlaceholder();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("char",charGson);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    Log.d("logtest", "onHelperLinkerClick: " + bundle.getParcelable("char"));
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));
    ft.commit();
```

Here, charGson is a properly defined class implementing Parcelable.  The line

```
    ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));
```

throws the following null pointer exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object
>   reference

It's unclear to me how to fix this problem.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If there's not already a `Fragment` in `container`, `findFragmentById(R.id.container)` will return null, and that `remove()` call will throw that Exception. Also, `FragmentTransaction`s only work on `Fragment`s, so that `remove()` call isn't going to do anything to your `ViewPager`, `AppBarLayout`, etc., unless they're part of a `Fragment`'s `View`.

Comment: where is your `fm` defined ?

Comment: fm was defined in the main activity's onCreate() method.  Mike M, you're right, findFragmentById() is returning null.  I'm working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

just try changing fm with `getSupportFragmentManager()`
so it would become

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: the fm is not null; that part is working.  Mike M.'s comment above put me on the right path - I'll update when I've got a better answer.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong.. so you want to swap the `fragment` on `buttonClick` and `fragments` are added into `ViewPager` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case exactly the same exception was thrown on the attempt to remove fragment that was `null`. You can insert a code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(null).commit();
```

and see your error log. The problem is that exception will be throwed not on this string, but little bit later somewhere inside of Android sources and you do not see which of your code strings was the reason of the exception.